# Mysql select distinct but limit the distinct values

Tags: mysql

This might be confusing but what I want to do is a basic select distinct columnx limit 3, the problem I have is it returns 3 rows, but I only want to get all values from one distinct columnx.

```
id|columnx  
1 |here  
2 |here  
3 |Idontwant  
4 |Apple
```

so I want a query that will return 1 and 2.  The problem is columnx could be anything and I cant just say where columnx = 'here'

The limit 3 comes into play because it's hard coded into my C# app.  The issue is i also set a hashset based on columnx, i have to have that columnx static for all records.  However, with every query i put together there is the possibility that with my limit i'll return 2 values in columnx, which are distinct values however, i can only have distinct columnx value per query.

No what I want is all values that belong to columnx, in this example columnx ='here', when i do a distinct all I want back is the first distinct result, not 'Idontwant' or 'apple' regardless of the limit.

Here is the query and it works.

```
SELECT id,columnx
FROM sites where columnx= (select distinct columnx from sites limit 1) limit 3
```

Comment: You're right, it is confusing :)  I'm pretty sure I don't understand what you're asking. Where does the `LIMIT 3` come into play? And which columns do you want to be `DISTINCT`?

Comment: see edit hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want the **id** values for three distinct **columnx** values. Is this right?  Try this:

```
SELECT id, columnx
FROM table AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(columnx) AS columnx
    LIMIT 1
) AS t2 ON (t1.columnx = t2.columnx);
```

I also wonder if you need some ORDER BY in there somewhere, but your question doesn't mention that, so I've omitted it--essentially meaning that you'll get three semi-random **columnx** values.

Comment: no, see edit, I want all results for 1 distinct columnx, the limit is just because i dont want my app to me a memory hog

Comment: @Mike, okay, answer updated then.  You shouldn't need any LIMIT 3 anywhere with this query--the `LIMIT 1` should do exactly what you want.

Comment: i need the limit because of memory in C# app.

Comment: it doesn't like your distinct(columnx) says unknown column

Comment: Hmm, yeah still having issues, see my edit i actually worked out the query thanks to the idea you gave me.

Comment: That looks like a reasonable adaptation. What issues are you still having?

Comment: you result still returns 0 records, i'm probably doing something wrong

Comment: That's very strange... I don't see how it couldn't return something.  But at least you found the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not sure what you are asking either but it sounds like you want to return the ids for those rows where there are duplicate values in columnx (limit the result to 3).

```
SELECT id, columnx
FROM tablename
GROUP BY columnx
HAVING ( COUNT(columnx) > 1 )
LIMIT 3
```